# VBA adding values from a form equals 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a user form. The user will enter numbers (sometimes with a decimal value). Out of a possible 6 values I want to display the average (usually all 6 fields but sometimes less). I have a label field that I want to display the value of the average with the current values as the user enters them.

I set it up similar to previous forms I have that work, but with this one it returns 0 regardless of the numbers I put into the text fields. Below is the code in a simple form that still returns 0.

```
Private Sub txtDb6_Change()
    Dim txtDb1 As Long
    Dim txtDb2 As Long
    Dim txtDb3 As Long
    Dim txtDb4 As Long
    Dim txtDb5 As Long
    Dim txtDb6 As Long
    Dim dbSum As Long
    dbSum = (txtDb1 + txtDb2 + txtDb3 + txtDb4 + txtDb5 + txtDb6)
    MsgBox (txtDb1)
    MsgBox (dbSum)
End Sub
```

Both message boxes show 0 with any numbers I enter into the text fields. Why is it doing this? How do I fix it?

Edit: I have also tried the code without assigning the text fields. In this version it concatonates the txtDb values.

```
Private Sub txtDb6_Change()
    dbSum = (txtDb1 + txtDb2 + txtDb3 + txtDb4 + txtDb5 + txtDb6)
    MsgBox (txtDb1)
    MsgBox (dbSum)
End Sub
```

Comment: You have six `Long` variables which haven't been assigned a value, so their default value is 0.

Comment: You're dealing with text boxes and `+` concatenates text. If you want addition, you have to convert the text to a number first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `txtDBx` are TextBox on Userform.

```vb
Private Sub txtDb6_Change()
    Dim dbSum As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 6
        dbSum = dbSum + Val(Me.Controls("txtDb" & i).Text)
    Next
    MsgBox dbSum
End Sub
```

The default property for a TextBox is the `Value` property. The type of return is `String`. `txtDb1 + txtDb2` is equivalent to `txtDb1 & txtDb2`.